# why is the touch command not recognized in ruby command prompt

Tags: ruby

Just simply trying to make a file in ruby however it says that the touch command is not recognized, any ideas?[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLbGT.jpg)

Comment: It's an OS thing (mostly). Do the instructions assume you're using macOS or Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Use [FileUtils#touch](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-touch) from inside Ruby:

```
require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.touch 'bcc.rb'
#=> ["bcc.rb"]
```